# Slow query with UNION ALL

Tags: mysql, union

I've got a query which gives me the desired result, but takes forever to execute. Can anyone give me any advice to speed up this query?

Here's the query:

```
SELECT StudentDB.studentid,
    ClassDB.classID,
    ClassDB.class_level,
    ClassDB.class_title,
    ClassDB.TIME,
    ClassDB.teacher,
    StudentDB.first_name,
    StudentDB.last_name
FROM StudentDB
INNER JOIN AttendanceDB
    ON StudentDB.studentid = AttendanceDB.studentid
INNER JOIN ClassDB
    ON AttendanceDB.classid = ClassDB.classID
WHERE StudentDB.studentid NOT IN (
        SELECT studentID
        FROM AttendanceDB
        WHERE (
                class_time >= '$todaysdate1'
                AND class_time < '$tomorrowsdate1'
                )
            AND (
                furikae = '0'
                OR furikae = '2'
                OR furikae = '1'
                )
        )
    AND DATE (AttendanceDB.class_time) = '$datecheck'
    AND AttendanceDB.furikae = '3'

UNION ALL

SELECT StudentDB.studentid,
    ClassDB.classID,
    ClassDB.class_level,
    ClassDB.class_title,
    ClassDB.TIME,
    ClassDB.teacher,
    StudentDB.first_name,
    StudentDB.last_name
FROM StudentDB
INNER JOIN RegDB
    ON StudentDB.studentID = RegDB.studentid
INNER JOIN ClassDB
    ON ClassDB.classID = RegDB.classid
WHERE StudentDB.studentid NOT IN (
        SELECT studentID
        FROM AttendanceDB
        WHERE (
                class_time >= '$todaysdate1'
                AND class_time < '$tomorrowsdate1'
                )
            AND (
                furikae = '0'
                OR furikae = '2'
                OR furikae = '1'
                )
        )
    AND ClassDB.day = '$dayofweek'
ORDER BY TIME ASC,
    class_title ASC
```

Basically my database structure is like this:

```
StudentDB
ClassDB
RegDB
AttendanceDB
```

StudentDB (this one has a lot of columns with data like students' phone numbers which are unrelated and I will remove to abbreviate this)

```
studentid   int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
first_name  text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None    
last_name   text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
class_level text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
```

ClassDB

```
classID int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
class_title text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
class_level text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None    
day text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None        
time    time            No  None        
teacher text    latin1_swedish_ci       No  None
```

RegDB

```
regid   int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT  
classid int(11)         No  None    
studentid   int(11)         No  None
```

AttendanceDB

```
attendanceID    int(11)         No  None    AUTO_INCREMENT
studentid   int(11)         No  None        
classid int(11)         No  None        
class_time  timestamp       on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP No  CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP     
furikae int(11)         No  None
```

RegDB links StudentDB to ClassDB, which student attends which class.
AttendanceDB records which student actually attends which class, as well as recording what students will join (in the future) a class which is not their regular class.

What I want to do with this SELECT is get all the students who are registered to a class or who have an irregular appointment, minus the students who have already been marked as signed in for the day.

As I said, this outputs the correct result, but is extremely slow.

Comment: Pls share the results of the explain and the create table statements for all underlying tables, so we can see the indexes.

Comment: Sorry, as you can tell I'm new to stackoverflow. Is there a link somewhere that can tell me how best to format my post for readability?

Comment: help center: http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: Thank you. I have a lot of reading to do. I think my bigger problem is that I don't understand your question. I have never had any formal instruction in programming so I lack some necessary common sense. Are there any resources that can instruct me in how to answer your questions more completely?

Comment: explain: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html show create table: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html

Comment: i don't understand why everyone has to give the new people the most complicated instructions possible. Go to phpMyAdmin - I'm making the assumption that you have it - Click on the table, then click "Export". Viola, you got your table structure.

Comment: @Pamblam 1. There are dozens of mysql management sws around, you cannot assume that the OP has phpmyadmin installed. 2. The fact that sy has little reputation on SO does not mean that they are new to programming as well.

Comment: no, it doesn't. however, him stating that he's new to programming is pretty good reason to assume he's new at programming. also, i don't know the stats, but i'll bet the amount of php servers that utilize PMA is somewhere in the 90th percentile, so I'd say that's a pretty good assumption as well.

Comment: New to programming me is back. I am using phpmyadmin. I am having difficult figuring out how to get the sql results in nice plain text like everyone seems to like. Is this acceptable formatting? 'attendanceID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  studentid int(11) NOT NULL,
  classid int(11) NOT NULL,
  class_time timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  furikae int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (attendanceID)'

Comment: Are u using indexes and force index

Answer (score 1):

let's call the first part of the union as query1 and second part of union as query2 . Now in query1 AttendenceDB is intermediate table b/n studentDB and ClassDB and in query2 RegDB is intermediate table b/n studentDB and ClassDB. and other conditions are same. If we union the reconds of RegDB and AttendenceDB first and then join this result of union with studentDB and ClassDB , we can avoid unnecessary joining.

Comment: Sounds a sensible suggestion. Provide more details and rationale and I will upvote it. In its current form, however, it feels more like a comment, rather than an answer.

Comment: let's call the first part of the union as query1 and second part of union as query2 . Now in query1 AttendenceDB is intermediate table b/n studentDB and ClassDB and in query2 RegDB is intermediate table b/n studentDB and ClassDB. and other conditions are same. If we union the reconds of RegDB and AttendenceDB first and then join this result of union with studentDB and ClassDB , we can avoid unnecessary joining.

Answer (score 1):

More of a detailed question I can later edit with a solution.  To better understand your data structure, let me clarify the following for myself (and any others).

StudentDB - obvious.  One record per student.

ClassDB - list of all possible classes that are offered, and could have multiple instances of the same class, such as Programming 101, but may be offered on different dates, different semesters, who is teaching a particular instance, etc.

RegDB - listing of all entries where a student is registered for a specific class offering. So each record is 1:1 for student : class.

AttendanceDB - attendance on a per student : class : date.  I would ASSUME the Attendance table has the class ID of attendance too.  If a student has 5 classes, they may show up for class 1-3, and leave early for classes 4-5.  If this was public schools K-12, and a student was leaving early for a Dr. appointment or so, you knew they were there for some classes, but not all.  If College, similarly, no guarantee they have multiple classes for a given day, but could attend one class, but not necessarily all classes.

So, from this, I would look at it this way.  First, give me all classes that qualify for the date in question (ClassDB).  Then to the registration table for who was signed up for it, then to the student registered.  Those would always be a valid JOIN.  From that, a CONDITIONAL join to the attendance table based on the nuances / status

If WOULD help to see the structures of the tables, even if abbreviated to confirm columns associated / needed for the query.   I would expect the class table to have the date range it might be applicable for... Such as class from Sept 1, 2015 to Dec 18, 2015.

Hence my TEMPORARY solution.  I added the Furikae field so you could get ALL and look at the results as a baseline consideration to this query.

```
SELECT 
      S.studentid,
      C.classID,
      C.class_level,
      C.class_title,
      C.TIME,
      C.teacher,
      S.first_name,
      S.last_name,
      ADB.furikae
   FROM 
      ClassDB C
         JOIN RegDB R
            on C.ClassID = R.ClassID
            JOIN StudentDB S
               ON R.studentid = S.studentID
               LEFT JOIN AttendanceDB ADB
                  on C.ClassID = ADB.ClassID
                 AND S.StudentID = ADB.StudentID
                 AND ADB.class_time >= '$todaysdate1'
                 AND ADB.class_time < '$tomorrowsdate1'
   WHERE
          '$datecheck' BETWEEN C.StartDate and C.EndDate
      AND C.day = '$dayofweek'
      AND (    ADB.Furikae IS NULL
            OR ADB.Furikae = '3' )
```

Now, all you would have to do is apply an additional AND clause based on the Furikae field.  I put in an EXAMPLE of such criteria as I don't know the purpose of this Furikae status field.  Also, the confirmation of the attendance is specifically looking for the current date basis as a student could have attended a week ago, but NOT attending based on "today".

For indexes, I would suggest the following.  Again, not knowing if the class table has a from/to date consideration

```
table       indexed on
ClassDB      (classID, StartDate, EndDate )
RegDB        (classID, StudentID )
StudentDB    (StudentID) -- would expect as it is primary key
AttendanceDB (classID, StudentID, class_time, Furikae )
```

Comment: I tried editing the original post with the tables being used. Sorry that the formatting isn't very good. I tried running your query (after removing the from/to date section because it is not present in the table). It correct outputs the records which have no entry yet, but it doesn't output the irregular one class enrollments from the RegDB (the ones which are marked with the attribute of furikae=3)

Comment: Sorry, it seems like I misunderstood your comment a bit (it's the early morning here in Japan). Here is the purpose of the furikae field: when it is set to 0, it records the student as having attended class, 1 records the student as having been absent, and 3 records an irregular attendance request for the future. So for example, when we record an irregular attendance for 1 week in the future it is listed as furikae = 3, then when the students attends class another record is made as furikae =0

Comment: @BenjaminJones, so you may want to edit your question and show some of the sample data for your Attendance table showing these 0, 1 and 3 records with respective dates.  And since you state 3 = a week in the future, show sample data with two weeks and how the result.  I THINK I am very close to what you need but dont want to edit until I am sure.